# why the gridview_sorting method is not fired in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method called `gridview1_Sorting` which works correctly when I click on header in table, but I want to call it automatically after the text inside search box changes and when the table change to the next from paging footer.

I think I should call this method manually from `grdView_PageIndexChanging` and from the method which detects checkbox state changes:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e) 
{
    SetSortDirection(SortDireaction);
    firstTable.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + _sortDirection;
    DataView dv = new DataView(firstTable);
    GridView1.DataSource = firstTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    SortDireaction = _sortDirection;

    int columnIndex = 0;
    foreach(DataControlFieldHeaderCell headerCell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells) 
    {
        if (headerCell.ContainingField.SortExpression == e.SortExpression) 
        {
            columnIndex = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.GetCellIndex(headerCell);
        }
    }
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[columnIndex].Controls.Add(sortImage);

}

Image sortImage = new Image();
protected void SetSortDirection(string sortDirection) 
{
    if (sortDirection == "Asc") 
    {
        _sortDirection = "Desc";
        sortImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/u.png";
    } else 
    {
        _sortDirection = "Asc";
        sortImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/d.png";
    }
}
```

I tried the following two options:

```
this.GridView1.Sorting +=
 new GridViewSortEventHandler(GridView1_Sorting);
```

and

```
this.GridView1.Sorting += GridView1_Sorting;
```

but none seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve d this problem by using gridview1.sort(e.SortExpression,SortDirection.Ascending);
but I think there is another solution by firing  gridview.sorting event but I cant do it